# Error while converting wsdl2Java using cxf - Attribute group must have ref name set

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

CXF Vesion - 3.1.5[tried with 2.x also] (i tried to generate java code from xsd also. no luck. )

Command -

```
MK-MacBook-Pro:bin mk$ ./wsdl2java -p com -d /Users/mk/Desktop -client -server -all -exsh false -dns false -dex false -verbose -autoNameResolution -noAddressBinding -allowElementReferences http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl
```

Result :

```
WSDLToJava Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer$XmlSchemaSerializerException: Attribute group must have ref name set

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer$XmlSchemaSerializerException: Attribute group must have ref name set
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:424)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer$XmlSchemaSerializerException: Attribute group must have ref name set
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.addSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:640)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:727)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:165)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:416)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer$XmlSchemaSerializerException: Attribute group must have ref name set
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeAttributeGroupRef(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:568)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeAttributeGroup(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:529)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchemaChild(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:2412)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchemaElement(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:1665)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaSerializer.serializeSchema(XmlSchemaSerializer.java:132)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.addSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:638)
```

Comment: Hu Mukesh, did you find a solution to this problem?